# Validating encrypted passwords in grails

Tags: validation, grails, encryption, passwords, encode

In grails I can set the password field to have a minimum size constraint of 5 (arbitrary).  The problem is that I use spring security service to encode my password and the encoded/encrypted password is much longer than 5 characters almost no matter what value I put in.

Another forum response suggested doing that validation in the save method.  Has anyone else tackled this problem and knows a way around it?

Spring security does not provide a decode method (probably for security purposes)... so I guess one idea would be to get a different password encoder that could decode the password for validation purposes... but my instinct says that spring security leaves this out for a good reason and maybe I should too...

```
static constraints = {
    username(blank: false, unique: true)
    password(minSize: 5, blank: false, unique: true,
        validator: { passwd, user ->
            return passwd != user.username
    })
    passwordRepeat(nullable: false,
    validator: { passwd2, user ->
        return passwd2 == user.password 
    })
}
```

So I'm using the static constraints to validate as most other variables are validated this way.

My apologies for the unreadable comment.

Thank you,
-Asaf

Edit: I think a simple fix is as mentioned above, doing the validation in the save method (before encryption), but I just feel like someone somewhere must have had to deal with this issue before.  I mean there's so many websites that require passwords and that yell at you if it's too short, if it doesn't contain both lowercase and uppercase letters, if it doesn't have a symbol... How do all of them do the various validation methods they use?

Comment: im not sure what the issue is....how are you trying to validate the password?

Comment: static constraints = {
  username(blank: false, unique: true)
  password(minSize: 5, blank: false, unique: true,
   validator: { passwd, user ->
    return passwd != user.username
  })
  passwordRepeat(nullable: false,
  validator: { passwd2, user ->
   return passwd2 == user.password 
  })
 }

So I'm using the static constraints to validate as most other variables are validated this way.  Unfortunately, this validation is done only after the password is encrypted.

Comment: thats unreadable in the comment, please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't decode what Spring Security encodes... That's md5 or sha-256 !!! That's exactly the purpose of the crypting process. Then, you can't know what's the password even if the databases files are stolen

To validate passwords, you need to prompt the user for a clear one, (transmit in https, please) and then encode it with the same algorithm. Then, you have to compare it to the encoded password you stored

Use the class [DigestUtils](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/codecs/DigestUtils.html) to encode your received password with the same algorithm used the first time. This is a Spring Security Config `grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm`

And yes, you have to validate before saving... For that we have added a metaclass in Bootstrap

```
String.metaClass.validateAsPassword
```

to have a unique point from which validating our passwords before saving them

Comment: perfect answer. You could add some javascript validation in addition.

Comment: @Ralf thanks ;-) You're right, Javascript is more client friendly, and can be used for syntactically checking passwords (length,composition) before sending it to the client for comparison. There are also supporters for double encoding (client/server, 2 different algorithms), even on an https line.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use String.metaClass.validateAsPassword?  I tried googling it but couldn't find an example of how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: I think for now I'm going to take Ralf's suggestion and go with javascript validation.  I'm going to utilize this free available code I found here: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-password-validator